# What is the execution sequence of Nested Master Pages?

Tags: master-pages, nested

Are Nested Master pages difficult to maintain ? Further what is the cycle of its execution ?... it would help me a lot in testing... i read about master pages on my own blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after doing a bit or R&D I finally got it. The execution sequence of Nested master pages is as follows:

First the load event of the Content Page is fired.
Second the load event of the Child Master Page is fired.
Last the load event of the Main Master Page is fired.

After this the event function related in the content page is fired... like the click event of button.

Further the nested master pages do get some issues while we update the pages, but we can overcome it by doing some good planning at the time of designing the application pages and master pages layout.